# First Java Program - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse

After creating a number of Android apps using Java in Eclipse. I now need to create a stand alone Java program so that I can create an sqlite database - that will eventually be used in a future Android app.

I am using the SQLJet library from http://sqljet.com and have copied their example code.

When I try to run the code by using the "Run" button in Eclipse I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:        org/antlr/runtime/RecognitionException
at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine$2.runSynchronized(SqlJetEngine.java:282)
at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine.runSynchronized(SqlJetEngine.java:217)
at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine.readSchema(SqlJetEngine.java:276)
at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine.getOptions(SqlJetEngine.java:299)
at nlmc.loader.apps4care.com.Test.main(Test.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.runtime.RecognitionException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

Now as the code has been copied without change, I am guessing there is nothing wrong with that and I suspect that I don't have my environment set up correctly. As a newbie Java developer (normally C#) I'm struggling to make sense of what the problem is. never mind the solution.

Code now working and the database is created. Unfortunately looks like it is not compatible with the sqlite3, the version Android uses. Back to the drawing board...!

Comment: copied from where? did you write "hello world" java program before?

Comment: I suspect that you don't add some jar.

Comment: I have added the jar file and the code builds OK so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @msangel - the code is from the http://sqljet.com website, from the same people who provide the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program needs the class org.antlr.runtime.RecognitionException. See here for a list of jars where you can find it: http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.antlr.runtime.RecognitionException

EDIT: And here you can see all the dependencies for SQLJet: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tmatesoft.sqljet/sqljet/1.1.1